# Javascript function variable double pipe symbol

Tags: javascript

in the process of learning Javascript and have come across this line, it looks like a function variable to me but I can see what the double pipe symbol does. Could someone explain to me what this does ?

```
var fn = fn || {};
```

Many thanks

Comment: What this does is if a variable called `fn` already exists within the current scope, reuse it. Otherwise, put an empty object in that variable. `||` is the OR operator. And this technique is often useful when you want to share a variable with other scripts but don't know if they created the variable before yours or not

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick response, I get it now. It's hard to search for answers like this online because, well how do you phrase the search ?

Answer (score 0):

It's an OR operator. Meaning the value will be the first value that's doesn't evaluate to falsey(null values, undefined and 0 all evaluate to falsey). If the first value is falsey the second value will be taken.

In your example if fn is first falsey, it will receive the value of {}. Otherwise it will keep its original value.

For more read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Comment: That's great, much appreciated